# Following a Computation Related to Hitting Time of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, markov-process

I'm trying to follow the following computation:

For a fixed $h >0$ and $x\in D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ we have (let $\tau$ be an exit time from $D$ and $B_t$ be a brownian motion started from $x \in D$):

$$\textbf{P}^x(\tau > h) = \textbf{P}^x(\forall t \in (o,h]: B(t) \in D) \\
= \inf_n \textbf{P}^x(\forall t \in (1/n,h]: B(t) \in D) \\
= \inf_n \textbf{E}^x \big[ \textbf{P}^x(\forall t \in (1/n,h]: B(t) \in D) \big]  \\
= \inf_n \textbf{E}^x \big[ \textbf{P}^{B_{1/n}}(\forall t \in (0,h-1/n]: B(t) \in D) \big] $$

I get lost at the last two lines:

1. Where does the expectation suddenly come from in Line 3?
2. I think Strong Markov Property was used in the 4th line, but I've only seen this formulated in terms of expectations. So I'm having trouble deciphering what's going on here?

Thoughts?

Comment: 1. $E^x(c)=c$ for any (deterministic!) constant $c$... so there is no harm in adding an expectation. 2. Write $P^x$ as an expectation [i.e. use that $P^x(A) = E^x(1_A)$] and use the strong Markov property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for line three in the original computation.  To get line four, I would write:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}^{x}\left\{B(t) \in D \, \, \text{for all} \, \, t \in (\frac{1}{n},h]\right\} &= \mathbb{E}^{x}(1_{\{B(t) \in D \, \, \text{for all} \, \, t \in (\frac{1}{n},h]\}}) \\
&= \mathbb{E}^{x} \left(\mathbb{P}^{B_{1_{n}}} \left\{B(t) \in D \, \, \text{for all} \, \, t \in \left(0,h - \frac{1}{n}\right]\right\} \right)
\end{align*}
by the Markov property.